# Handling Git and Mercurial in 1 project

Tags: git, mercurial

We want to use an external service but that service uses only Git to push code to their platform.

For now I have setup both Mercurial and Git in the project's directory. It works fine so long as I work on the same computer, but when I change computer and need to pull, I get lots of conflicts between what Git pull and Mercurial pulls.

My question is, what would be the best setup to handle all of that? I thought of having commands that copy code over to another directory when I commit but I'm not sure it's the best.

Any recommandations?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the semiofficial [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git/wiki/git-remote-hg) bridge (or maybe [hg-git](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git)) and treat it just as another repository.

Comment: Don't have git and hg operate on the same directory. Make a clone so that each VCS has its own directory to mess around with.

Comment: There's a [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/) plugin for mercurial which lets you push and pull git repos directly, so you don't even need to maintain two parallel repos. And if you're using TortoiseHg I think it's bundled with it.